# How to match partial words in elastic search text search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field `name` in my elastic search with a value of `Single V`

Now if i search it with a value of `S` or `Sing` , i don't get no result , but if i enter a full value `Single` , then i get the result `Single V`, the query i am using is as following :-

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "singl"
    }
  },
  "sort": []
}
```

This gives me no results , do i need to change the mapping/setting for name or analyzer ?

**EDIT:-**

I am trying to create the following index with the following mapping/setting

```
PUT my_cars
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "sortable": {
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "my_tokenizer": {
            "type": "ngram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 36,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "sortable"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But i get the following error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "analyzer [tokenizer] must specify either an analyzer type, or a tokenizer"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "analyzer [tokenizer] must specify either an analyzer type, or a tokenizer"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elasticsearch by default uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) for the `text` field if no analyzer is specified. This will tokenize `"Single V"` into `"single"` and `"v"`. Due to this, you are getting the result for `"Single"` and not for the other terms.

If you want to do a partial search, you can use [edge n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) or a [Wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

The mapping for the Edge n-gram tokenizer would be

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 6,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

In the index mapping given above, there is one bracket `}` missing. Modify your index mapping as shown below

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "sortable": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }                                 
      },                                    // note this
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 36,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 50
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "sortable"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tried this , but i get an error , can you check my edit :) thanks btw

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik there is one bracket missing in your mapping, the `analyzer` part should be closed and then the `tokenizer` part should start. Added the updated mapping in the answer above, please go through it and let me know if this resolves your issue?

Comment: thanks got it works fine :) , yes the tokenizer being inside analyzer error was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the default analyzer. The field is broken into tokens because of the analyzer - [Single,V].
Match query will try to find an **exact search** of any of the query tokens. Since you are only passing `Singl` that will be the only token, which is not matching any of the two tokens which are saved in the DB.

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "user.id": {
        "name": "*singl*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use [wildcard queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)